Centering logo in centered menu
How to alter the css (using flexbox) for this menu so that the center li (logo) is absolutely centered, and the other links are centered between equal sized, evenly distributed frames that they are centered in? Right now they are spaced evenly with padding from the center out. Using the Divi theme, and built the header custom.



.custom-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-left,
.menu-right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10; /* Ensure the logo is on top */
}

.custom-menu li {
  list-style: none;
}

.custom-menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  /* Optional: add background, border, or other styles here */
}

enter code here

This is just an example of the code which you can use. You need to chnage your HTML also corresponding to this

I figured it out by myself.
https://codepen.io/judyhicks/embed/XWLENdx?default-tab=html%2Cresult
